# schtasks - request not supported

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I have a number of tasks scheduled on Windows Server 2008. I am trying to batch update those tasks with the following script:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in (
    'schtasks /Query /FO csv ^| find /V "TaskName"'
) do (
    schtasks /change /tn %%a /ru mydomain\myuser /rl HIGHEST /rp *
)
```

For every single task it asks me for a password but it updates the task successfully. However when I try to put my credentials in the command (like below) it fails with error `REQUEST NOT SUPPORTED`

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in (
    'schtasks /Query /FO csv ^| find /V "TaskName"'
) do (
    schtasks /change /s system /u mydomain\myuser /p mypassword /tn %%a /ru mydomain\myuser /rl HIGHEST /rp *
)
```

I run the script as administrator. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what are the results of `'schtasks /Query /FO csv ^| find /V "TaskName"'` secondly, you run the command as admin, but you connect remotely, meaning it is running as the user you specify remotely, not admin.

Comment: I don't think the result of /query is a problem. If it was it wouldn't work for the first script (without credentials) . Anyway, it's a list of tasknames. Yes I connect remotely but my user has admin rights.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't contain any strange character

Comment: I have provided full server name and removed /u parameter and it works! Thanks